# Why my GAE - Primefaces app works locally but not in remote?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Google App Engine 1.9.20, Primefaces 5.2 and Java 7 for my web application. Everything works fine locally, but when I deploy on the remote server, Primefaces is not working. I have my page content displayed in plain text (tested with an "hello world") but the Primefaces tags are not decoded.

When I display the source code of my web page, it looks like this instead of html code:

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="110" id="north" resizable="false">
            <ui:include src="templates/header.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" size="250">
            <ui:include src="templates/menu.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center">
            Hello world !
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Primefaces libraries are located in the war/lib folder, added in the app build path and I followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-jsf-2-example/) to configure the project.

Am I forgetting some configuration on the dashboard or elsewhere ?

Thanks

Comment: Are normal jsf components rendered?

Comment: No jsf component rendered. I should start by this information